# NginX reverse proxy (https:8443 to http:80) with multiple sites not working

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy

Been working on this for a few nights and I can't seem to get it to work.  This is on my home network where my ISP blocks incoming traffic to TCP-80 & 443 so, I have a couple of sites running on strange ports; don't be alarmed.

**My current setup:**

I have a Raspberry Pi that runs a couple of wikis via NginX.  The sites are available to the outside world via a couple of subdomains (example: https://wiki.somedomain.com:8443/ & https://wiki2.somedomain.com:8443/) and I have a legit wildcard cert for *.somedomain.com.  This was a pet project of mine and has been working in the current config for a few years.

**Moving the Setup:**

The Pi is getting a bit old and I've started playing around with Docker and got my sites moved to a couple of docker containers on a faster and more stable machine that run on TCP-80.  Locally, I can hit those via IP and they run fine; they just don't have a cert.  My goal was to set up a reverse proxy with my legit cert and have it redirect the traffic, coming in on https:8443 to http:80.  As near as I can tell, this is the way of going about this type of setup where you have multiple Docker containers and don't have certs for all of them.  If I'm misunderstanding something, stop me right here and tell me I'm wasting my time; the bang-head-here sign on the wall next to me will thank you.

**NginX Config:**

`nginx -t` says this config is fine but, clearly, something wrong.  If it's logging an error, I don't know where; I've ran a few `tail -f` commands and found nothing being added.  Neither Firefox nor Brave give me any meaningful errors, other than *this site can't be reached*, as near as I can tell.  Any ideas?  Am I wasting my time?

```
# SSL Info
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cherryblossomfarmette.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cherryblossomfarmette.com/privkey.pem;

## Server Info
# IT Wiki
server {
        #listen 80;
        listen 8443 ssl;
        server_name wiki.cherryblossomfarmette.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.100.35:8080;
        }
}
```

**Docker**

Here's one of my docker compose files.  The other docker compose file is the same except it *listens* on 8081.

```
docker run \
    --detach \
    --name=dokuwiki-it \
    --env "TZ=America/New_York" \
    --publish 8080:80 \
    --volume "/home/tome/Docker/IT_Wiki/config:/config" \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    lscr.io/linuxserver/dokuwiki
```

**Access.log - when configured for HTTP:80**

When I comment out `listen 8443 ssl;` and hit the site across the LAN, the site loads and I see records in access.log.

```
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:19:58:59 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:19:58:59 -0500] "GET /lib/exe/taskrunner.php?id=start&1642640339 HTTP/1.1" 200 42 "http://192.168.20.102/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
```

**Access.log - when configured for HTTPS:8443**

When I comment out `listen 80;` and hit the site across the LAN, the site loads and I see records in access.log.  Of course, I get the typical the SSL cert nag in the browser because I'm not coming through with the virtual host name like I use from outside the network.

```
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/images/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3744 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/exe/css.php?t=dokuwiki&tseed=b378c07b31317225e36675986970a553 HTTP/1.1" 200 39260 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/images/license/button/cc-by-sa.png HTTP/1.1" 200 379 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/images/button-donate.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 187 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/images/button-css.png HTTP/1.1" 200 297 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/images/button-html5.png HTTP/1.1" 200 305 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/images/button-dw.png HTTP/1.1" 200 398 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/images/button-php.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 207 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/images/email.png HTTP/1.1" 200 370 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/lib/exe/css.php?t=dokuwiki&tseed=b378c07b31317225e36675986970a553" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/images/external-link.png HTTP/1.1" 200 431 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/lib/exe/css.php?t=dokuwiki&tseed=b378c07b31317225e36675986970a553" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/exe/taskrunner.php?id=start&1642640673 HTTP/1.1" 200 42 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
192.168.20.131 - - [19/Jan/2022:20:04:34 -0500] "GET /lib/tpl/dokuwiki/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 7406 "https://192.168.20.102:8443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Who is running in docker? nginx? wikis? both? give config of docker as well please (compose file or the used run statements)

Comment: Sorry about that, @araisch.  I have since gone back and added one of my docker compose files.  Only the wikis are in docker.   The Pi, which has the cert, is running NginX.

Comment: For logging you can send the logs to a file to be sure: `error_log logs/error.log warn;` and `access_log logs/access.log`. It is strange that nginx does not log anything, if nginx is not logging anything your request does probably not reach nginx. Maybe you check locally by `listen 80` and `server_name _` to catch all and remove ssl and dns from the equation. It is easier to increase complexity from a minimal working setting to a more complex one instead of otherwise round..

Comment: @araisch I added logs to the config and did some tail commands while I flipped the config back and forth between HTTP & HTTPS.  I also simplified the config to just do one of the wikis.  As you said, it's easier to start simple and complicate the mousetrap as needed.

Comment: I took it another step further and tweaked my hosts file (/etc/hosts) and added an entry that pointed right to the Pi (with the valid cert and the `proxy_pass` code in the config) and and the site loaded.  Not really sure what to make of all that...  I'm guessing the config above works but why doesn't it work from outside my network?

Comment: If nginx works for local devices you're halfway through. First of all the first level domain must resolve to your public IP. Then the router needs to know what to do with the request (Firewall has to accept 8443/tcp inbound and Port Forwarding for 8443/tcp to your nginx server). Then the nginx server has to accept inbound traffic from the router (may be checked with other device in local network). Use wireshark on the nginx host to determine if the requests from external networks arrive at all. Or if they are altered

Comment: I can ping the domain and my external IP is resolved.  The router has known what to do with the traffic for years as, it has been sending HTTPS:8443 to the Pi for a few years now.  In fact, when I disable the NginX config doing the `proxy_pass` work and enable the old config that has been used for years, the site loads.  The only difference between the two configs is that one (in use for years) loads the site from a local directory and the other passes the traffic to the docker container on another machine.

Comment: Yeah sorry for asking but there are confusingly that many players in this game. May you reach the wikis via NGINX-IP:8443 from another device? And then you added the domain to hosts and then it's working either? But not from outside (which is equal by using the domain and NOT add it to hosts)..

Comment: Yes, I can get to the Pi, running NginX with `proxy_pass` and a valid cert from other machines on the network but, obviously, I'm coming in via the local IP so the cert "looks" invalid to the computer.

Comment: Did you check with wireshark on nginx host, if the requests from external are coming in? And if they are looking the same like internal requests (test http, https is err.. encrypted..) :)

Comment: I haven't gotten to that part yet.  I am hoping to get WireShark installed this week.  Every time I test this stuff I have to take down my sites so I tend to do it early in the morn.  I haven't had an early morn in several days.

Comment: Well, the server I was using for all this decided to crap out this week.  So much for being more stable than the old Pi...  Regardless, the more I think about it, the more I think it has something to do with my Unifi USG not doing something properly with the redirected packets.  It works inside my network but not coming in from outside.  To me, that seems like a routing issue and not an issue with NginX.  I think I'll get my server rebuilt and then start poking the Unifi forums.  If I ever get it figured out, I'll have to note it here to help others.